# Ubuntu don't recognize windows7 partitions

Tags: partitioning, windows, macbook-pro

I have a MacBookPro9,2 and I have installed windows7 64bits:

- "C" partition: Windows7 64bits;
- "D" partition: NTFS for Data;
- Free space to install Ubuntu 14.04;

The problem is when I try to install Ubuntu, I am surprised that the hard disk is all free (partitions "C" and "D" don't appear).

I have also tried with Ubuntu 10.10 and I have the same problem.

Thanks for your response!

Comment: Can you post a list of your partitions? Paste the output of fdisk -l. Do you have a mbr or guid partition table?

Comment: Just a precision: when I try Ubuntu without install it. it recognize all partitions. The issue is in the partitioning step

Comment: Maybe a driver is not loaded. Do you see the disk and no partitions or nothing at all? fdisk -l output would help :)

Comment: I see the disk (500 GO free). but no partitions

Comment: The output of fdisk -l command is:

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa60a087c

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   186245119    93019136    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       186245120   771971071   292862976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       771971072   976771071   102400000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: Here is the same problem: [link](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/06/why-is-windows-8-on-ssd-invisible-to-ubuntu-12-10s-installer/)

Comment: RESOLVED:Disable GPT, In the terminal while “booted” from the live CD type “sudo gdisk /dev/sda” (change “/dev/sda” to whatever is appropriate to access your hard disk). The program is likely to complain that it’s found both MBR and GPT data,and will ask which to use.
At the “Command” prompt, type “x” to enter the experts’ menu.
At the “Expert command” prompt, type “z” to “zap” (destroy) the GPT data.Type “y” in response to the confirmation about destroying the GPT.Type “n” in response to the query about blanking the MBR. /!\: If you answer “y” here, you’ll destroy your Windows partition(s)!